# Fabric's Crashlytics crashed by himself

Tags: android, crashlytics, runtimeexception, google-fabric

I added crashlytics to my app, then added

```
    Answers.getInstance().logContentView(new ContentViewEvent()
            .putContentName("Principal")
            .putContentType("Informacion"));
```

to my MainActivity and other activities to track...

It worked fine till today since I got this into google play console:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2306)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2366)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800 (ActivityThread.java:149)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1284)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5297)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:908)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:703)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.singleton (Fabric.java:275)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.getKit (Fabric.java:525)
  at com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers.getInstance (Answers.java:34)
  at com.destander.nutrirte.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:68)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6020)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1105)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2259)
```

The thing is that it failed and crashlytics didn't reported at all.
Now I'm looking for a way to avoid more crashed than the ones made by my own mistakes!

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. This seems very strange, our SDK is very defensive around crashes happening. Is it possible that the Answers call is being made before Fabric is initialized?

Comment: Hi Mike
I added Fabric to android studio, then install Crashlytics following the guides. As I can see all work is made by the script and no task from me was needed. Then couple of day after that added Answers like the one I show in my question and all worked fine.
Any guide or place to look at?

Comment: Did you add that new log before the Fabric init?

Comment: Hi Mike, how can it be? the line of code "Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());" was not there!
I did got stats and most all functions working!
Now there is a new app version with the fix and we will see what happens!

Comment: Mind blown, I don't know how that worked before.

Comment: Thanks for the help! No crashes till now!

Comment: I forgot that it has an splash activity and the Fabric init is in there!

Comment: Thanks for sharing, glad you're all set :)

Comment: We're getting the same crash. I'm initializing fabric in application on create ```@Override
 public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);```

crash is only on some devices, not all devices. Can you advise @mike-bonnell

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this consistently on those devices?

Comment: @MikeBonnell, I see about 50 cases of a very similar crash (IllegalStateException in Fabric.singleton after a call to Crashlytics.log), but I'm using Firebase.Crashlitics and I do not do any "Fabric.with" initialization (probablly Firebase does it?). But I cannot reproduce the problem... Any suggestion?

Comment: Without a reproducible case, it will be hard to determine. You can try reaching out to Firebase support or upgrade to the latest versions of the SDK, but a repro really is needed.